# How to skip or pass a parameter into a child node in JSON object declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, maps

Sorry for being a noob on JSON. I have a parameter I want to pass into calling the JSON object.
**JSON:**

```
{
 "environments":{
  "test":{
   "on":true
  }
 }
}
```

On the above, the 2nd node `test` is dynamic depending on the environment you are at. I would like pass a parameter value so that key can change based on your declaration (no arrays used above and this is a third-party API that I cannot change).

**Code:**

```
const envName = 'test' // This can be changed to 'uat' too
if(body.environments.test.on === true) //I need the 'test' to change or parameterised.
{
// Do something
}
```

Basically, I would like to skip the key 'test' or pass the value from `envName`. I included a wildcard `*` and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets to parameterize the environment:

```js
let body = {
 "environments":{
  "uat":{
   "on":true
  }
 }
}

const envName = 'uat';
if(body.environments[envName].on === true)
{
   console.log('true');
}
```

or `Object.values()` to do the wildcard scenario:

```js
let body = {
 "environments":{
  "uat":{
   "on":true
  }
 }
}

const envName = 'uat';
if(Object.values(body.environments).some(x => x.on === true))
{
   console.log('true');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for .. in` loop to go through the nested elements of `body.environments` and check if on is true or not like this:

```js
const body = {
 "environments":{
  "test":{
   "on":true
  }
 }
}

for(let b in body.environments) {
  if(body.environments[b].on) {
    console.log(body.environments[b].on);
  }
}
```